# WPF DataGrid Grouping Not Updating On Updates

Tags: wpf, datagrid, updates

Our WPF DataGrid does not update its groups when we edit items. We group by field X, and the item for which we change field X still stays in the same group. How do we make the grid always dynamically keep its groups up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one of our team members discovered the IEditableObject interface, which allows the level of control we needed to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know for the DataGrid, but for other other grouping controls in WPF this is done automatically. Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for the grouping property and does it fired? Was the current row of the DataGrid updated?

Comment: The data in the row updates, but the position doesn't - it stays in the same (now incorrect) group.

Comment: And yep, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged